# R: how to toggle html page selection in web scraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(rlist)
theurl <- getURL("http://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=2022181",.opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE) )
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)
```

I'm trying to scrape the 2016 table data from the above webpage. If I change the `Year` to 2010, the url changes to `http://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1966487`.

I want to automate my algorithm so that it can obtain the table across different `Year`, but I'm not sure how I can obtain the unique identifiers (e.g. `1966487`) for each page automatically. Is there a way to find the list of these?

I've tried looking at the html source code, but no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With rvest, you can set the value in the form and submit it. Wrapped in `purrr::map_dfr` to iterate and row-bind the results in to a data frame,

```r
library(rvest)

sess <- html_session("http://legacy.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=2022181")

baseball <- purrr::map_dfr(
    2017:2015,
    function(y){
        Sys.sleep(10 + runif(1))    # be polite

        form <- sess %>% 
            html_node(xpath = '//form[@action="index.php"]') %>% 
            html_form() %>% 
            set_values(year = y)

        sess <- submit_form(sess, form)

        sess %>% 
            read_html() %>% 
            html_node('#TTdata') %>% 
            html_table(header = TRUE)
    }
)

tibble::as_data_frame(baseball)    # for printing
#> # A tibble: 4,036 x 38
#>      `#`              NAME  TEAM    LG  YEAR   AGE     G    PA    AB     R
#>    <dbl>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#>  1     1 Giancarlo Stanton   MIA    NL  2017    27   159   692   597   123
#>  2     2        Joey Votto   CIN    NL  2017    33   162   707   559   106
#>  3     3  Charlie Blackmon   COL    NL  2017    30   159   725   644   137
#>  4     4       Aaron Judge   NYA    AL  2017    25   155   678   542   128
#>  5     5     Nolan Arenado   COL    NL  2017    26   159   680   606   100
#>  6     6       Kris Bryant   CHN    NL  2017    25   151   665   549   111
#>  7     7        Mike Trout   ANA    AL  2017    25   114   507   402    92
#>  8     8       Jose Altuve   HOU    AL  2017    27   153   662   590   112
#>  9     9  Paul Goldschmidt   ARI    NL  2017    29   155   665   558   117
#> 10    10      Jose Ramirez   CLE    AL  2017    24   152   645   585   107
#> # ... with 4,026 more rows, and 28 more variables: H <int>, `1B` <int>,
#> #   `2B` <int>, `3B` <int>, HR <int>, TB <int>, BB <int>, IBB <int>,
#> #   SO <int>, HBP <int>, SF <int>, SH <int>, RBI <int>, DP <int>,
#> #   NETDP <dbl>, SB <int>, CS <int>, AVG <dbl>, OBP <dbl>, SLG <dbl>,
#> #   OPS <dbl>, ISO <dbl>, BPF <int>, oppOPS <dbl>, TAv <dbl>, VORP <dbl>,
#> #   FRAA <dbl>, BWARP <dbl>
```